# Does Henry Morgan age?

Tags: tv, forever

Does he age in-between deaths? Or does he remain the same age regardless of how long he lives between deaths?

Comment: I haven't watched this, but the wikipedia article says "*when he dies Morgan disappears almost immediately, and returns to life in a nearby body of water without clothes*" and "***Having also stopped aging, his long life has given Morgan broad knowledge and remarkable observation skills***". It would seem that he's fixed at a specific age; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forever_(U.S._TV_series)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the 2nd episode (*Look Before You Leap*), Abe, played by Judd Hirsch, was showing Henry his online dating profile. When he showed Henry his profile photo, it was a picture of Abe from many years ago. As explanation for using a misleading photo, Abe said to Henry

> Well not everybody can remain 35 forever.

Based on that comment, it seems that Henry does not age between deaths and remains the same age.